# Fusion Charts is same as sencha charts?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, sencha-touch, fusioncharts

I have experiences with sencha chart which has touch faclity as iPad has.But Fusion provides swf file , but we can see them through javascript in iPad.but interaction is less than sencha.Because zooming,pinching,rotating faclities are not in Fusion.Am I right? or is it possible in fusion as scencha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In FusionCharts 3 they will automatically fallback to Javascript if you're on a device that doesn't support flash. As you mentioned the interactivity on a phone or tablet is limited, FusionCharts doesn't have support built in for touch events. This is where Sencha Touch Charts excels, its not a "fallback" implementation its a full featured chart solution made specifically for multitouch devices.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried either of the two but I highly recommend http://www.highcharts.com/ good set of api and easy to use..

Comment: yup it is.. by default it adds a watermark.. but you can disable it.. I am using it in my production environment

Comment: will it work in mobile browsers such iPad and iPhone with zooming,rotating pie,pinching?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Looks like a nice charting library.

Comment: i hope it wont support mobile device features